# How to make multiline edittext in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, multiline

I try to create an edittext dynamically with LayoutParams.MATCHPARENT for its both width and height.
I have tried the following code, but it is still not working.

```
EditText editor = ....;
LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
editor.setLayoutParams(params);
editor.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP);
editor.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
editor.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
editor.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
//editor.setSingleLine(false);
editor.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
editor.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE | EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_IME_MULTI_LINE);
editor.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
editor.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
editor.setTransformationMethod(null);
```

The code above let me to enter several lines, and an 'ENTER' button is displayed in the keyboard, but as I type on the edittext, the edit text scrolls horizontally if the width is not enough to display the text.
Can anybody please help me how to make the edittext multiline?

Comment: any words? did you succeed with this? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 8):

Try this following code

```
editor.setSingleLine(false);
editor.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this code

```
    txt.setSingleLine(false);
    txt.setLines(14);
    txt.setMinLines(13);
    txt.setMaxLines(15);
    txt.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP);
```

Comment: Hi, your post has been flagged as "low quality", probably because it consists solely of code. You could massively improve your answer by providing an explanation of exactly how and why this answers the question?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
android:scrollHorizontally="false"
```

for the edittext

Answer (score 1):

Add below line into your code, it may help you.

```
editor.setSingleLine(false);
```